# How to test an href attribute of an anchor tag that leads to a redirecting url?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redirect, jestjs, react-testing-library

If you try to visit [https://reactjs.dev](https://reactjs.org), you'll be redirected to https://react.dev. The status code of the response in this case is **308** (from the network tab in the browser). I am trying to write a unit test for a similar case using *react testing library*. When testing the working (destination) URL, the test passes. See the following code:

**Passing test:**

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

test("verify link is responging", async () => {
    render(<a href="https://react.dev">Click Here</a>);
    const href = screen.getByRole("link").getAttribute("href");
    const res = await fetch(href);
    console.log(res.status);         // 200
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)     // passes
})
```

**Failing test (for which I actually want to write the test):**

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

test("verify link is responging", async () => {
    render(<a href="https://reactjs.org">Click Here</a>);  // redirects to "https://react.dev"
    const href = screen.getByRole("link").getAttribute("href");
    const res = await fetch(href);   // throws an error at this step and exits
    expect(res.status).toBe(308);         // doesn't reach this line
})
```

**This gives the following error:**

```
 console.error
    Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden
        at dispatchError (C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Courses\testing\udemy\color-button\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Object.validCORSHeaders (C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Courses\testing\udemy\color-button\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:75:5)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Courses\testing\udemy\color-button\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:672:25)
        at Request.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at Request._processResponse (C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Courses\testing\udemy\color-button\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\http-request.js:196:12)
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Courses\testing\udemy\color-button\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\http-request.js:101:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:647:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:127:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
        at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:66:53)
      at Object.validCORSHeaders (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:75:5)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:672:25)
      at Request._processResponse (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:196:12)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:101:12)

FAIL src/App.test.js
  × verify link is responging (374 ms)

  ● verify link is responging

    TypeError: Network request failed

      at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:566:18
      at Timeout.task [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:516:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.908 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

**What I want to do:**
I want to write a test so that if the response status is `308`, get the redirected link and test it until you get a response status of `200`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing with `https://reactjs.org` is because its an external API called during your tests, and it has [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restriction different than the `jsdom` setting that Jest uses.

If you are using Jest v28 or above, you can do bypass this by setting the Jest config `testEnvironmentOptions.url` like:

```
testEnvironmentOptions: {
  url: 'https://reactjs.org',
}
```

Refer: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironmentoptions-object

---

If you are using versions lower than v28, you can use the `testURL` config:

```
testURL: 'https://reactjs.org',
```

Refer: https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/24.x/configuration#testurl-string